# Trouble with Adjusting eShell Prompt and Tabbing

Tags: eshell

I've setup a custom prompt for eShell but, on doing tab completion (and pressing enter), the shell gets stuck at being read-only.

I've noticed that, if I tab-complete something and then move the cursor (say, back one character) before pressing enter, it won't enter this state, however.

I thought it might be an issue with how I was setting `eshell-prompt-regexp` but, other than there supposedly being a tab character at the end, I think it's a perfect regexp match.

Running `emacs -q` and then loading the below elisp recreates the problem; you can then open an eShell buffer, do something like `ls ~/` and then tabbing to complete, hit enter, and then experience the same issue.

```el
(require 'cl)

(defun trim-string (string)
  "Remove white spaces in beginning and end of STRING.
White space here is any of: space, tab, emacs newline (line feed, ASCII 10)."
  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\`[ \t\n]*" "" (replace-regexp-in-string
                                               "[ \t\n]*\\'"
                                               ""
                                               string)))

(defconst number-to-string-approx-suffixes
  '("k" "M" "G" "T" "P" "E" "Z" "Y"))
(defun number-to-string-approx-suffix (n &optional binary)
  "Return an approximate decimal representation of NUMBER as a string,
followed by a multiplier suffix (k, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y). The representation
is at most 5 characters long for numbers between 0 and 10^19-5*10^16.
Uses a minus sign if negative.
NUMBER may be an integer or a floating point number.
If the optional argument BINARY is non-nil, use 1024 instead of 1000 as
the base multiplier."
  (if (zerop n)
      "0"
    (let ((sign                                          "")
          (b                          (if binary 1024 1000))
          (suffix                                        "")
          (bigger-suffixes number-to-string-approx-suffixes))
      (when (< n 0)
        (setq n    (- n)
              sign   "-"))
      (while (and (>= n b) (consp bigger-suffixes))
        (setq n                             (/ n b) ; TODO: this is rounding down; nearest would be better
              suffix          (car bigger-suffixes)
              bigger-suffixes (cdr bigger-suffixes)))
      (concat sign (if (integerp n)
                       (int-to-string n)
                     (number-to-string (floor n))) suffix))))

(setq eshell-prompt-regexp "
┌(.*)
├\\(\\[.*\\]─\\)?([0-9]+ file[s]?, [0-9]+[kMGTPEZY]+iB)─(.*@.*)
└─> ")
(setq eshell-prompt-function (lambda ()
                               (let ((purple     '(:foreground "#622f7d"))
                                     (gray       '(:foreground "#434541"))
                                     (white      '(:foreground "#FFFFFF"))
                                     (bold-white '(:foreground "#FFFFFF" :weight bold))
                                     (off-white  '(:foreground "#d1d1d1"))
                                     (cyan       '(:foreground "#00d1e0"))
                                     (green      '(:foreground "#7BE128"))
                                     (yellow     '(:foreground "#eab700"))
                                     (red        '(:foreground "#F52749")))
                                 (concat
                                   "\n"
                                   (propertize "┌(" 'face gray)
                                     (propertize default-directory 'face purple)
                                     (propertize ")\n"             'face   gray)
                                   (propertize "├"  'face gray)
                                     (propertize "(" 'face gray)
                                       (let ((num-of-files (-
                                                             (length
                                                               (directory-files
                                                                 default-directory))
                                                             2)))
                                         (concat
                                           (propertize (number-to-string num-of-files) 'face     white)
                                           (propertize " file"                         'face off-white)
                                           (propertize (if (= num-of-files 1) "" "s")  'face off-white)
                                           (propertize ", "                            'face off-white)))
                                       (propertize
                                         (number-to-string-approx-suffix
                                           (reduce
                                             '(lambda (result newCar)
                                                (+
                                                  (if (string= (car newCar) "..")
                                                      0
                                                    (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (cddddr newCar)))))))
                                                  result))
                                             (directory-files-and-attributes
                                               default-directory)
                                             :initial-value 0))
                                         'face
                                         white)
                                       (propertize "iB" 'face off-white)
                                       (propertize ")─" 'face      gray)
                                     (propertize "(" 'face gray)
                                       (propertize (getenv "USER")            'face      cyan)
                                       (propertize "@"                        'face off-white)
                                       (propertize (trim-string
                                                     (shell-command-to-string
                                                       "hostname"))           'face     green)
                                       (propertize ")\n"                      'face      gray)
                                   (propertize "└─>" 'face gray) (propertize " " 'face white)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out; I've seen this come up in a few places but no one ever seems to provide an answer so for future people who run into the issue.

`eshell-prompt-regexp` isn't looking to match the whole prompt, it seems, but just the line that cursor/text will be (inputted) on.

So

```el
(setq eshell-prompt-regexp "└─> ")
```

would've been the answer to my problem; introducing a newline to this variable immediately causes its behavior and functionality to break.

This single line, targeting the last line of my prompt, provides perfect performance and functionality.